# Assigning a static IP to Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS

Tags: networking, server, dhcp

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Server in my machine on a separate hard drive alonside my Windows 7 installation. The Windows OS has full network connectivity and internet access through the Ethernet, but the Ubuntu installation does not.

I have a hunch that this could be because my router which sees 2 different computers with the same MAC address, and the DHCP is not working. How do I assign the machine a common static IP so that both partitions can use my network? I am new to Ubuntu and I couldn't figure out which file to edit so that I can assign the static IP.

Comment: Hi & Welcome to **AU**. I'm actually lost when you say Windows & Ubuntu on a separate partition. Because either it has to be a dual boot which will run separately or else it has to be a VM (virtual machine). Can you please elaborate on how both of these OS operates and configured?? :)

Comment: You WILL have problems with two **simultaneously** connected machines with the same MAC address, but not if they are running at different times. So your problem is probably in some other place, if I understand well (and even if you have the server in a VM, the VM will solve the MAC problem for you; each VM has its own unique MAC).

Comment: See  https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/network-configuration.html . The router doesn't see two computers ; it sees the same interface card (NIC) no matter which is running.

Answer (score 116):

I'm not sure if this will solve your problem, but this answers your question and I think it's worth a shot.

To assign a static IP, you need to edit `/etc/network/interfaces`.

The interface will probably be called `eth0`.

The current entry will look something like:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

You will need to change this to:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
   address 10.253.0.50
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   network 10.253.0.0
   gateway 10.253.0.1
   dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

You will have to change the numbers around depending on your network, but you can find out the information by checking out `ipconfig` from Windows.

**Make sure you choose an address outside the address space of the DHCP server.**

Then restart networking `sudo service networking restart`. If that gives you trouble, reboot the machine.

Comment: @dan08- I believe dns-nameservers is also needed here. I suggest you edit your answer.

Comment: Restart `eth0` with `sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0` instead of the last command.

Comment: In my env gateway ended with .254, not sure if this applies for everyone. Other than that this answer works for 14.14

Comment: Does not work by me, I still got DHCP IP. Sadly it is coming from a hybrid modem + router device, which does not have to feature to set static IP by MAC address. :S I might need to buy a router. :S According to `ifdown eth0` the interface is not configured.

Comment: but now the network would start automatically

Comment: hi, in ubuntu16.04,  you can't modify this configure file. you shall use network-manager ui or cli to modify it. thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Set your IP address changes in `/etc/network/interfaces`. Example:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static

address 192.168.1.128
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Don't give your DNS configurations in `/etc/resolv.conf` because while we restart the server sometimes the configuration get erased.

So use `vim /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` (while updating configs in this it doesn't get removed)

example:

```
search  (domain name)
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Save and then restart your server, this fixed my static issue! :)

Comment: Bare in mind that your device name can be other than `eth0`. Mine are `enp1s7` and `enp2s15`. I have 2 LAN card.

Answer (score 8):

I found I had to include the dns settings:

```
auto lo enp0s25

iface lo inet loopback

iface enp0s25 inet static
    address 192.168.1.128
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    dns-search example.com
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

See https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/network-configuration.html

Comment: you missing gateway

Comment: yes, thanks @Pavel Niedoba, now that I look more closely on my server, I'm not sure how I missed that.  Fixed.

Comment: 8.8.8.8.7 is not a valid IP address

Answer (score 0):

### Change the interfaces config:

`$ sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`

Then replace the following configuration:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto ens160
iface ens160 inet static
# Enter your specific IP address
        address 192.168.1.130
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.1
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Then trigger it via:

```
$ sudo service networking restart
```

or

```
$ sudo ifdown ens160; ifup ens160
```

If you encountered with an error, do the following command:

`$ ip addr flush dev ens160`

Also, you can reboot the os: `sudo reboot`

---

[**NOTE**]:

- `ens160` is my ethernet name, you can check it via `$ ifconfig` command.
- This works and tested in *Ubuntu 14.04* and *16.04*.
- Here's *Ubuntu 18.04* [configuration method.](https://askubuntu.com/a/1057594/772449)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 20.04 doesn't have `/etc/network/interfaces` and uses `/etc/netplan/<config file>.yaml` instead.

The `.yaml` config file is auto generated and can have many names but as long as it has `.yaml` extension it should work fine. Mine was `50-cloud-init.yaml` on one machine, `00-installer-config.yaml` on another.

To set the ip to `192.168.0.102`, in `/etc/netplan/<config file>.yaml`:

```
network:
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: false
            addresses: [192.168.0.102/24]
            gateway4: 192.168.0.1
            nameservers:
              addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4,192.168.0.1]
    version: 2
```

You can look up what your current gateway is using `ip route` and put that in instead of `192.168.0.1`

Also instead of `eth0` you can have a different name for your network. If so, keep your network's name there.

Then `sudo netplan apply`

This kicked me out of SSH because I was SSHed through an old ip. I had to reboot the computer manually. Restarting router is a good idea too at this point to clear possible ip conflicts.

Also I found suggestions to edit the generator of this yaml file in `/etc/cloud` but I found no fool-proof docs how to do this. Instead, Canonical provides https://netplan.io/examples with a whole bunch of copy-paste configurations for the `config.yaml` file, which seem like a great approach for most cases.