# How to setup a static IP on Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: networking, server, ip, 18.04

I've seen some people saying the file to set static ip is still `/etc/network/interfaces`

And I've seen other people saying that in 18.04 it's now on `/etc/netplan` (which people seem unhappy about)

I've tried putting this:

```
version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.1.9/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.1.1, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

In my `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml` and doing `sudo netplan apply` but that just kills the servers connection to the internet.

Comment: Is it a desktop or a server?

Comment: Is this a fresh 18.04 install or upgrade from another version?

Comment: Sorry I should've said this in the text, its a fresh install of 18.04 server.

Comment: The most simple solution for me was, to specify a static IPv4 address right **during installation** (together with subnet, gateway, etc.). Simply fill out some wizard fields, no messing with configuration files.

Comment: You can also do this on routers. Steps are self-explanatory in the router config.

Comment: I wish there was one line answer to it. BTW what's wrong with /etc/network/interfaces file ?

Comment: Sigh. Thanks, Canonical, for needlessly complicating simple things.

Answer (score 36):

All the answers telling you to directly edit `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml` are wrong since CloudInit is used and will generate that file. In Ubuntu 18.04.2 it is clearly written inside the file :

```
$ cat /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    ethernets:
        eno1:
            dhcp4: true
    version: 2
```

So you should not edit that file but the one under `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/` if you still want to use CloudInit.

Another way is to completely disable CloudInit first by creating an empty file `/etc/cloud/cloud-init.disabled` (see https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/boot.html) and then the other answers are OK. Under Ubuntu 18.04.2 I had to use `dpkg-reconfigure cloud-init` to let it take into account the file `/etc/cloud/cloud-init.disabled`. I think this is a little bit weird.

I suggest you to rename the file (not the right name since `50-cloud-init.yaml` let us think it still uses CloudInit).

Then you may end up with a file name `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` which contains the configuration below. Note the use of the `networkd` renderer instead of `NetworkManager` because the configuration is on a server.

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.1.246/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
         addresses: [192.168.1.1]
```

Comment: It works great. This should be the best answer. 50-cloud-init.yaml as stated shouldn't be modified.

Comment: If still using CloudInit, you need to do a `sudo cloud-init clean -r` to get the change to take, as per veperr's answer (at least for me on Ubuntu Server 18.04.3).

Comment: ...plus the `renderer` line is no longer valid it seems (and is missing in the base version of the file that you edit).

Comment: Simply adding a custom file under `/etc/netplan/##-*.yaml` works as well. Such as: "/etc/netplan/99-custom-network.yaml". This also follows the https://netplan.io/examples/ instructions. In "conf.d" type config areas you should always opt for a custom/new file if possible instead of editing installed package files. It's why we have these "numbered file" areas. These default #'ed files can frequently get overwritten. And YES: If you have a "50-cloud-init.yaml", it should NOT be used. It is system generated as noted in comments. Why people keep posting this as an answer is anyone's guess?

Comment: I wrote "Then you may end up with a file name `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`". Isn't it the same thing you propose ?

Comment: Yep. But, you can add it directly to `/etc/netplan`. Any **new** files under this area will persist through reboots. I gave you +1 for 1: saying not to edit cloud-init, and 2: Creating a *new file* in a numbered area (& not editing ANY preexisting/system ones). Note: You do not even necessarily need to disable anything so long as you are updating the same network interface. A higher numbered yaml will override all previous repeated directives (or should). So "50-" will be read in AFTER "01-". If you renamed your file "99-" you wouldn't have to disable "50-" - if that makes sense. See my answer

Comment: I have 20+ servers running for 4 years with regular upgrades and maintenance. Never once, 50-cloud-init.yaml has been reset or overwritten.
From what I have noticed, cloud-init (as the name says) is run once, at server creation and then it won't be automatically reissued again.

Answer (score 15):

### This is set a static IP instruction in *Ubuntu-Server 18.04 and 20.04*

```
$ sudo nano /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
```

#### Then replace your configuration, for example, the following lines:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens160:  # Your ethernet name.
     dhcp4: no
     addresses: [192.168.1.137/24]
     gateway4: 192.168.1.1
     nameservers:
       addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

---

#### Apply changes:

```
$ sudo netplan apply
```

In case you run into some issues execute:

```
$ sudo netplan --debug apply
```

---

[**NOTE**]:

- `/24` is equivalent with `255.255.255.0`
- `ens160` is your ethernet name, you can get it using `$ ifconfig`
- *Ubuntu 16.04 and 14.04* network-interface [configuration](https://askubuntu.com/a/1041461/772449) have a different method.
- The file is in [YAML format](https://yaml.org/start.html): Use spaces, no tabs.

Comment: not able to ping after assigning static IP address

Comment: OK....I'm able to ping after doing `service networking restart`

Comment: I wouldn't do that since that file is generated by CloudInit

Comment: only works if your ethernet is "ens160", check your ethernet "ls /sys/class/net/" and replace "ens160" with it.

Comment: @sailfish009 I mentioned it before in the NOTE section in my answer.

Comment: @BenyaminJafari Oh i see.

Comment: Changes to this file are rewritten on reboot - even says so in comment at top of it. This answer is wrong.

Answer (score 8):

I've found another way using cloud-init.

1. Edit the file `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/50-curtin-networking.cfg` - the contents seem to be the same as they would be in /etc/netplan.
2. clean, reboot and re-initialize `cloud-init` with this command:

   ```
   sudo cloud-init clean -r
   ```
3. That's it! Your system will reboot, `cloud-init` will re-initialize and pickup the change in `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/50-curtin-networking.cfg` and apply them to `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml` and all will be well. Verify with `ifconfig`.

Comment: 2 things. -> 1. Better to create your own "99-myconfig.cfg" file under `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/` so it's read in last and will overwrite any previous configs and will not be overwritten by possible system updates. 2. `ifconfig` _is defunct_. Use `ip` command now. For example `ip addr` will show same thing as ifconfig use to.

Answer (score 7):

Ubuntu 18.04 uses now Netplan to configure the network interfaces, so the configuration must be done in the file `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`, the documentation advises not to mess anymore with the old file `/etc/network/interfaces`. I have used this configuration with my Ubuntu Server virtual machine and it works so far, just make sure the info is correct; the `optional: true` setting supposedly speeds up the booting time by not verifying if the interface is connected or not, this is default, also there is no need to declare values not used, for example DHCP, if they are absent they are taken as disabled, also the default renderer in Ubuntu Server is `networkd` so there is no need to declare it. Taking the information from your post, it should be like this:

```
network:
    ethernets:
        eht0:
            addresses:
            - 192.168.1.9/24
            gateway4: 192.168.1.1
            nameservers:
                addresses: [192.168.1.1, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
            optional: true
    version: 2
```

Once you save the file, run `sudo netplan --debug apply` the `debug` flag will output more info and can help to detect any errors. Check the ethernet cable, if in virtual review the VM configuration. If using a WLAN I have read that it is a bit more tricky to setup but I haven't yet set up a machine connected to WiFi with this server version.

If you want more info about Netplan there is a website, it has some basic configuration examples.

https://netplan.io/

Comment: Wrong. DO NOT EDIT `50-cloud-init.yaml`, or any existing system generated files!

Answer (score 6):

Config file is in [YAML format](https://yaml.org/): Don't use **TAB** when configuring the file. It only works with **SPACE**.

Answer (score 3):

Writing a new answer as so many are just wrong.

Do not edit `50-cloud-init.yaml`, `00-installer-config.yaml` or **ANY** system generated files/package files.

From https://netplan.io/examples/ :

*"To configure netplan, save configuration files under /etc/netplan/ with a .yaml extension (e.g. /etc/netplan/config.yaml) .."*

The installer/[system](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Netplan/Design) did that. **Now you need to override it.**

Also consult `man netplan-generate` for the rules governing how the network configurations are read from `/etc/netplan/*.yaml` (and elsewhere).

##### To correctly update the netplan area to use a static IP over the default DHCP:

Edit/Create **a new file** (the prepended number+dash and .yaml extension are important):

`sudo nano /etc/netplan/99-custom-network.yaml`

Add your properly formatted [YAML](https://yaml.org/) to this file. A static IP example:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: [10.10.10.5/24]
      gateway4: 10.10.10.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [10.10.10.100,8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
  version: 2
```

(Note: My network device is `ens160` - not `eth0` - adjust as needed.)
Save.
Then do a `sudo netplan apply`.
Make sure your network interface looks right and is working (`ip ad` / `ping`).
Then do a reboot. Retest.

This follows the netplan.io instructions as well as the general rule of not editing any existing/installed files when possible. In `/etc/netplan/` and similar [conf.d/](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/etc-configuration-directories) type config areas you should always opt for a high numbered custom/new file (if possible) instead of editing any installed package files.

It's why they have numbered files in these configuration areas (in /etc/netplan/ and others). The higher the number on the file equates to when it is read in.

Therefore, something with "99-" prepended on it will generally be read in *last* and *OVERRIDE* anything that repeated before it. Therefore, if a network interface is set to DHCP in "00-installer-config.yaml", and/or "50-cloud.init.yaml", the settings for the same interface in a "99-*.yaml" file will override everything else read in previously.

Generally these installed YAML files will NOT get overwritten, but that isn't valid logic to not follow the conf.d "standard" of using custom files to override and avoid editing any installed files. It doesn't take any extra time. Drop a file in netplan. Done. So, there's no excuse as I have witnessed in comments of "well, it's worked so far..".

So, editing the default netplan *.yaml(s) will technically (usually) "work", but you should avoid using them when possible.

Answer (score 2):

Network configuration in 18.04 is managed via netplan and configured with cloud-init.
To change your network configuration edit the `50-curtin-networking.cfg` file in `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/`. If this file does not exist then create it.

Find your interface name

```
ip address show
```

Edit / create the cloud-init network configuration file

```
sudo nano /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/50-curtin-networking.cfg
```

To set a static IP address, use the addresses key, which takes a list of (IPv4 or IPv6), addresses along with the subnet prefix length (e.g. /24). Gateway and DNS information can be provided as well:

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.9/24
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
          addresses: [192.168.1.1, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

You can find more configuration options at https://netplan.io/examples

Reload the cloud-init configuration. This will reboot your server.

```
sudo cloud-init clean -r
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the setting what make it work.

```
$sudo nano /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml

network:
   ethernets:
     eth0:          
     addresses:
     - 192.168.1.9/24
     dhcp: false
     gateway4: 192.168.1.1
     nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 192.168.1.1
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4
        search: []
  version: 2  

$sudo netplan apply
```

restart the server

change eth0 to your adapter, find out your adapter using ifconfig.

Comment: Wrong. DO NOT EDIT 50-cloud-init.yaml, or any existing system generated files!

Answer (score 0):

To find available ethernet interfaces use `ip link show`

Then edit the 50-cloud-init.yaml file using `$sudo nano /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`

Add the configuration for available interfaces like eth0: and eth1:

```
network:
   ethernets:
     eth0:          
     addresses:
     - 192.168.1.9/24
     dhcp: false
     gateway4: 192.168.1.1
     nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 192.168.1.1
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4
        search: []
     eth0:
     addresses:
     - 192.168.1.9/24
     dhcp: false
  version: 2
```

Then use command `$sudo netplan apply` to apply the changes.

Comment: Wrong. DO NOT EDIT 50-cloud-init.yaml, or any existing system generated files!

Answer (score 0):

### How to setup a static IP on Ubuntu Server 18.04

Then edit the 50-cloud-init.yaml file using`$sudo vim /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`

---

```
network:
  ethernets:
    eno1:
        addresses:
        - 10.0.1.10/24
        dhcp4: false
        gateway4: 10.0.1.1
        nameservers:
            addresses:
            - 10.0.1.2
            search: []
version: 2
```

---

### Apply changes:

`$ sudo netplan apply`

Comment: I wouldn't do that since that file is generated by CloudInit.

Comment: Why oh why is every guide to setting a static IP on 18.04 telling me to edit a yaml file that says it is a dynamically created file that will not persist?  Another cruel joke from the Ubuntu developers that think it is ok to just break things by default...

Comment: Wrong. DO NOT EDIT 50-cloud-init.yaml, or any existing system generated files!

Comment: @B.Shea I have 20+ servers running for 4 years with regular upgrades and maintenance. Never once, 50-cloud-init.yaml has been reset or overwritten.
For what I have noticed, cloud-init (as the name says) is run once, at server creation and then it won't be automatically reissued again.

Comment: @DarioFumagalli Only 4 years? You're using broken logic: Just because nothing "broke" doesn't mean you are doing it the proper way. You should NEVER edit system installed config files **if** there is a way to avoid it. And there is clearly a way to avoid it in this case..

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
dhcp4: no
            dhcp6: no
            addresses: [172.23.4.2/24, ]
            gateway4: 172.23.4.254
            nameservers:
                    addresses: [172.23.4.1, ]
```

`[172.23.4.2/24, ]` is the additional thing I did on the `yaml` file.

Reference: https://serverspace.io/support/help/how-to-configure-static-ip-address-on-ubuntu-18-04/