# Setting a static IP address was failed

Tags: server, 18.04

The error messages shown in the attached image were displayed after a trial:

As you may assume, I've already set a static IP address on 50-cloud-init.yaml file. My settings are as follows:

This file is generated from information provided by
the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
network: {config: disabled}

```
network:
    ethernets:
        enp0s3:
            addresses: [192.168.0.101/24]
            gateway4: 192.168.1.1
            nameservers:
                    addresses: [192.168.1.1,8.8.8.8]
            dhcp4: no
    version: 2
```

And of course, I made the above changes take effect by running the following command: sudo netplan apply

SI there any solution you can provide? Please advise!

Comment: [How to setup a static IP on Ubuntu 18.04 - server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029531/how-to-setup-a-static-ip-on-ubuntu-18-04-server) may help.

Comment: Is this a cloud instance? If not, did you take the suggested steps to disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities? Your error messages are not showing. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.