# Assigning 2 Permanent IP Addresses In 18.04 Desktop

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, ip

There are 2 themes of IP addresses on my network:

- 192.168.0.###
- 10.#.#.#

  - 10.1.1.#
  - 10.2.1.#
  - 10.3.1.#
  - ...
  - 10.12.1.#

How do I assign permanent IP addresses to access the services in the 10.#.#.#

I tried:

```
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.9.1.100/24
```

Followed by

```
sudo  systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
```

Without success.  I am using Ubuntu 18.04 desktop and haven't found an answer specific to 18.04

Comment: Are you looking for a GUI or foa CLI method?

Comment: try this [How to Setup a Static IP on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029531/how-to-setup-a-static-ip-on-ubuntu-18-04-server)

Answer (score 1):

Add another IP-address via a GUI:

- Open the network settings / connection details (the exact steps depend on the desktop environment you are using)
- select the IPv4 tab
  [image: screenshot of network settings]
- click on the *Add* button
- fill the values you want into the fields
- click on *Save*