# Ip camera direct ethernet connection to lubuntu, while wifi internet

Tags: networking, lubuntu, internet, ethernet, camera

I have lubuntu 18.04 running on an Udoo X86. Internet access is through wifi and I have been trying all day to get a hikvision ip camera with static ip 192.168.1.64 to connect through the ethernet port with no luck. Nothing happens when I plug the cable into the eth port. I have tried setting up an ethernet connection with address 192.168.1.10 and mask 255.255.255.0, but since it is a direct connection I don't know if I need to enter a gateway or not. Am I doing this wrong or is there a problem with my ethernet port? Thanks!

Comment: You need to either connect it to PC using a crossover cable, or connect it to your Router and set it up to the same IP range.

Refer back to the camera manual again and you should find detailed instructions

Comment: Thanks Ahmadgeo, but I need to connect it directly as there will be no router at the install location. I have done it before with a dahua camera but it worked with no issues as soon as I plugged it in. I have already done all the camera configuration using a windows pc. I just need to set up an ethernet connection at the same time as a wifi connection on the Udoo.

Comment: Use a Cross Over Ethernet cable then, looks like the port in Udoo don't recognize the direct connection.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable

Comment: I thought virtually everything made in the last 20 years has Auto MDI-X (aka *Auto uplink and trade, Universal Cable Recognition and Auto Sensing*), does your computer support that? If it does, then apparently a crossover cable shouldn't make a difference. But if you happen to have a crossover cable handy already, it couldn't hurt to try it anyway. Also, how did you connect the camera to windows? Using the same cable, or even the same exact computer & port, only running Windows instead of Linux?

Comment: I looked up documentation and Udoo does support auto MDI-X, though whether or not it is working is unknown. With the PC, the port immediately recognizes that there is a device and I can ping the camera and then use the browser to view it. With the Udoo running lubuntu, I can't even ping it. I only need it to be recognized so that I can pull a video stream to zoneminder. I can connect it directly to a raspberry pi with no issues, but the Udoo is more powerful so I want to use it as the server. I'm thinking it's an issue with the ethernet port settings not working, but so far no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thanks for your responses. The issue I was running into was that I was trying to set the ethernet address using the gui interface and network manager, but in Ubuntu/lubuntu 18.04, you now have to use Netplan to configure networks. Once I followed these instructions, [How to setup a static IP on Ubuntu Server 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029531/how-to-setup-a-static-ip-on-ubuntu-server-18-04), it took a minute to set it up and have the udoo recognize the connection.

Comment: Hi @AI T i'm also trying to get my ip camera feed on my raspberry pi. Actually i'm not experienced in setting up ip camera could you please help me with it. My situation is I have an IP camera with (mentioned by manufacture )ip=192.168.1.88 which is connected to pi via lan; whereas my pi itself is connected to wifi, i'm accessing my pi via ssh on my pc . But when i try to access camera with above ip its not working saying "timeout=0 failed: No route to host" . Please help me with it ! Thanks in advance